# Set background image using css don't load the background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I get a console error when I try to set a background image using CSS.

My CSS code is:

```
body {

background-image: url("background.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

The error

```
GET http://localhost/myWeb/css/background.png 403 (Forbidden).
```

The CSS file and the image are in the same location.

Comment: Looks like an access issue. Make sure that IIS has an access to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check file permissions for image background.png ..

Comment: actually, it is a correct answer. My case the png file permission was -rw-------, after I changed to -rwxr-xr-x, it worked.